# CMake find_path() don't find what it should

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-language

I work on linux ubuntu 20.04 but i try in ubuntu 22.04 too

I have this part of CMakelist:

```
if(EXISTS "${MYPROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/build/include/config.hpp")
  Message("the file exist ${MYPROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/build/include/config.hpp")
endif()


  find_path(
    MYPROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR
    NAMES config.hpp
    PATHS ${MYPROJECT_ROOT_DIR}/build
    PATH_SUFFIXES include
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
    REQUIRED
  )
```

${MYPROJECT_ROOT_DIR} is a absolut path that my user has access

The config.hpp file does exist in the requested path (the message appears correctly and when I search in the folder I see it appear).

But with the find_path command i have this error:

```
 Could not find MYPROJECT_INCLUDE_DIR using the following files: config.hpp
```

Can someone explain with find_path doesn't work as expected?

My version of Cmake : cmake version 3.27.6

Comment: Where does this `config.hpp` file come from? If it's in the `build` directory it feels like it should be automatically generated, which means it either should always exist or you should have some other way of knowing if it exists or not.

Comment: Cannot repro, for me it finds the path correctly. Try to debug this issue by creating dummy project only with `cmake_minimum_required` and that command, and see if it works for you. Also, `MYPROJECT_ROOT_DIR` looks fishy, because cmake already provides many build-in variables like `PROJECT_SOURCE_ROOT`,  `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` etc ...